# How can I scale down graphics drawn with the OnPaint event to fit different resolutions?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm game designed for the resolution 2256x1504, but I need it to work on 1920x1080, the app is a game with no controls, instead everything is done with the form's `OnPaint` event, using `e.Graphic.DrawImage();` for drawing to the screen. When I open the game in 1920x1080, everything stays the same as if it thought the screen was still 2256x1504.

I tried using the form's `AutoSize` property, but it didn't help at all scaling down to different resolutions. I was expecting it to figure out what the screen would look like if it was in 2256x1504, and then scale that down to its correct size using the screen size.

I'm not using the `PictureBox` control, because it does a lot of background things that end up lagging my game, so I can't just switch to those to simplify things.

Comment: Use your design scale as the base scale of your drawings, then calculate a scale factor when the container Form is initialized (reading the size of the Screen where the Form is shown). Apply the scale to the objects you draw. If you use class objects to handle the shapes / images, you can apply the scale automatically when the objects are created and apply the scale while drawing only to objects that have a relative size (i.e., calculated on the fly)

Comment: I will try this if there is no easier way to do it, but if anybody else has some other way that doesn't involve me needing to change a lot of things using scale factors, then it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Graphics.ScaleTransform() is a quick way to get there.  But keep in mind that it is always better to scale up then to scale down, especially so when you use DrawImage().  So start the design with the minimum size you want to support.  DrawImage() gets grainy when scaled up, you can always letterbox if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I really was trying to avoid doing too much work by manually changing all my variables using scale factors, but Hans Passant was able to prevent that!